# Difference in execution time

Tags: python

When trying to measure the execution time of a piece of code for calculating the minimum value in a list (without using inbuilt method), I get different times for two different codes.

Code 1:

```
%%timeit 
minimum = None

for x in num:
    if minimum == None:
        minimum=x

    elif x<minimum:
        minimum=x

    else:
        continue

1.47 µs ± 186 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Code 2:

```
%%timeit 
minimum = num[0]

for x in num:
    if x<minimum:
        minimum=x

    else:
        continue

897 ns ± 65.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Why does such a big difference exist between these two pieces of code? There are hardly any differences. Is it because I used the data from a particular list location in the second code?

Answer (score 4):

You have one extra check in `Code 1` -- it's useful only the first iteration, but you keep checking on every iteration.  Since there's very little code, this slows down the program almost 2x.

BTW, `else: continue` does nothing -- Python naturally continues at the bottom of the loop.

Hmmm ... perhaps you didn't notice the difference in time units?  The measurements are 1470 ns vs 897 ns.

Comment: That is what I want to know. What aspect of the code caused the time difference? PS: The else part is kind of force of habit.